# Writing my own event emitter fails

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write an event emitter, based on [this totorial](https://howtonode.org/demystifying-events-in-node). 
But the final event `on('cooked')` does not fire, why?

```
var events = require('events');

function Dummy() {
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);
}

Dummy.super_ = events.EventEmitter;
Dummy.prototype = Object.create(events.EventEmitter.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: Dummy,
        enumerable: false
    }
});

function _cook(a,cb) {
    console.log('frying it',a)
    cb(a)
}

Dummy.prototype.cooking = function(chicken) {
    var self = this;
    self.chicken = chicken;
    self.cook = _cook; // assume dummy function that'll do the cooking
    self.cook(chicken, function(cooked_chicken) {
        console.log('callback')
        self.chicken = cooked_chicken;
        self.emit('cooked', self.chicken);
    });

    return self;
}

var kenny = new Dummy();
fried_chix = {type:'tasty'}

var dinner = kenny.cooking(fried_chix);

dinner.on('cooked', function(chicken) {
    console.log('we can eat now!')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your entire code is synchronous.

As part of calling `kenny.cooking()`, the `cooked` event is emitted (synchronously), but at that point you haven't yet attached a listener for that event.

If you make your `_cook` method asynchronous, it'll work:

```
function _cook(a,cb) {
  console.log('frying it',a)
  setImmediate(function() {
    cb(a);
  });
}
```